# Ansible failed undefined variable

Tags: ansible, bitbucket

I trying use simple ansible and receive the following error message

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'entregas' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in
> '/home/gustavo/Documents/ansible/roles/build/tasks/main.yml': line 2,
> column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
> syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name :
> Clone and pull\n  ^ here\n" }

My directory

```
.
├── build.yml
├── roles
    ├── build
        ├── defaults
            ├── main.yml
        ├── tasks
            ├── main.yml
```

And my files

build.yml

```
---
- name: Pull Git
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local 
  roles: 
  - build
```

Default -> main.yml

```
---
dest_path : /tmp/ansible/test
sh_key_path : /root/.ssh/id_rsa
entregas-web : **bit bucket ssh**
```

tasks -> main.yml

```
---
- name : Clone and pull
  become : true
  ansible.builtin.git :
    repo : "{{ entregas-web }}"
    key_file : "{{ ssh_key_path }}"
    dest : "{{ dest_path }}"
    refspec : '+refs/pull/* :refs/heads/*'
    force : yes
    version : master
```

that happen when i throw this command

> ansible-playbook build.yml -u root -vvvvv

or

> ansible-playbook build.yml -vvvv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable name is invalid. Valid variable names do not contain a `-` (dash).

This is why your error message mentions a missing variable `entregas`.

See the documentation on [variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names).